# If the length of the smallest and longest chord of the circle $x^2+y^2-4x-2y-20=0$ passing through $(5,1)$ is $s$ and $l$ respectively.

Tags: circles

If the length of the smallest and longest chord of the circle $x^2+y^2-4x-2y-20=0$ passing through $(5,1)$ is $s$ and $l$ respectively,then find the value of $s+l$.

This is a circle whose center is $(2,1)$ and the radius is $5$.I know that longest chord is diameter but how will we find the shortest chord length?

Comment: That has to be perpendicular to the diameter, why ?